# Kotlin parallel computation of large array

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a large array and need compute result based on each item of this array. My PC's processor has 2 cores.
I have compared different ways to achieve parallel execution in Kotlin.

I wrote simple example to illustrate this. First way is Java parallel stream, second is plain Kotlin map, third is coroutine version of map.

```
fun p() = runBlocking {
    val num = (0 until 1_000_000).toList()
    println(measureTimeMillis {
        num.stream().parallel().map { it * 2 }.collect(Collectors.toList())
    })
    println(measureTimeMillis {
        num.map { it * 2 }
    })
    println(measureTimeMillis {
        num.pmap { it * 2 }
    })
}

suspend fun <A, B> Iterable<A>.pmap(f: suspend (A) -> B): List<B> = coroutineScope {
    map { async { f(it) } }.map { it.await() }
}
```

The output (in ms.):

152
64
1620

Why pmap version is so slow? How to improve the code?

Comment: pmap creates a lot of intermediate Deferred instances.
Also, you can try avoiding Integer boxing, which will lead to a performance boost.

Comment: Deferred instances are the lesser problem. The problem is submitting the computation of each individual item as a separate task to the `Default` thread pool and then awaiting on each of them in the calling thread. That all of that incurs just one order of magnitude impact on performance is for me a very good result.

Comment: In terms of high-throughput parallelization, Kotlin doesn't have an offering comparable to Java streams.

Comment: Here's a quick way to eliminate some of the overhead in `pmap`: `chunked(100_000).map { async { map { f(it) } } }.map { it.await() }.flatten()`. It doesn't work on `Iterable` but on `List`, though.

Comment: You create a parallel task for each of 1000000 elements of the the input array. But you have no 1000000 processors, only 2 (the result of Runtime.getRintime().avalableProcessors()). Create 2 tasks and let each of tasks to process its own half of the array.

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` for those who want to copy paste Alexei's suggestion.