# Handling multithreading computation of big array

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a large array and need to do heavy CPU-work on each element of that array.

Based on [my similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491296/kotlin-parallel-computation-of-large-array), Mr. Alexei Kaigorodov suggests that the best way is to split computation each chunk of data on each separate thread.

There is my realization of algorithm using Kotlin coroutines:

```
suspend fun predictAll(movingVehicles: List<MovingVehicle>): List<MovingVehicle?> {
    val prevTime = Timestamp(Date().time)
    val nextTime = Timestamp(Date().time)
    val ctx = Dispatchers.Default
    val processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
    val chunks = movingVehicles.chunked(movingVehicles.count() / processors)
    val s = coroutineScope {
        val res = mutableListOf<Deferred<List<MovingVehicle?>>>()
        for (c in chunks) {
            val r = async(ctx) {
                c.map { predictLocation(it, prevTime, nextTime) }
            }
            res.add(r)
        }
        res.awaitAll()
    }
    return s.flatten()
}

private fun predictLocation(
    mv: MovingVehicle,
    prevTime: Timestamp,
    nextTime: Timestamp,
    relevance: Int = 5
): MovingVehicle?
```

It works, but maybe is there a better approach?
I'm looking for ExecutorService, but looks like it need more boilerplate code than coroutines does.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this community isn't intended for reviews of working code (maybe, just maybe: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for your request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a Kotilinic way of using coroutines. You submit async tasks which can execute concurrently and then you wait for them to finish.

One food for thought. Everything is executed in a thread. That means coroutines are also executed on a thread and if your task is blocking *the thread will be blocked*. Coroutines won't save there. So it is often a good idea to create a `Threadpool` with the properties which seems best for the application (backpressure mechanics, number of min/max threads etc.)

Now in your case, you have cpu-bound tasks, you can't achieve more performance by having large number of threads. For such tasks, practical application of [Amdahl's_law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) gives -

```
#threads = #cpu-cores - 1
```

Coroutines by default are backed by [common pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) which is the same number of threads as mentioned above, so seems good to keep default settings.

However multiple libraries might be using this pool, and if you have an IO blocking task in any of them, you will loose performance. I would recommend create your own ForkJoinPool and use it as dispatcher

```
val nOfThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1;
val ctx = ForkJoinPool( if (nOfThreads == 0) then 1 else nOfThreads).asCoroutineDispatcher()
```